# QGIS 2.14.3 Processing Dissolve error "local variable 'nElement' referenced before assignment See log for more details"

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

When I try to use Dissolve in Processing I get this error:

"local variable 'nElement' referenced before assignment See log for more details"

[image]

[image]

I have seen this problem reported in:  https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14612

So then I did what is recommended by  Alexander Bruy removed the processing folder from C:\Users\user.qgis2 however I still have the same problem, I did a Full Uninstall (delet all folders...) of Qgis and reinstalled from standalone installer QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.14.3-1-Setup-x86_64 but the problem persist.

I suspect that it is a bug...

PS: when I use the "Dissolve all" check, the process work, its only when I try to dissolve from a selected field that give me the error

QGIS 2.14.3
Windows 10 64bits (1511 10586.318)
Processing 2.12.99

Comment: GIS SE is a database of focused GIS questions with answers -- As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better idea how things are supposed to work. Unfortunately, this reads more like a bug report than a question.  If you have a specific task to accomplish, please **edit the question** to focus on that.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer ... yes I guessed that it seems like a bug report, but just wanted to know if  I was doing something wrong  with the tool

thank you very much! I´ll try to report the bug

Comment: Same problem here... there is also "Line dissolve" in Saga tools...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144191)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Vector polygon tools** > **Polygon dissolve (by attribute)** from **SAGA** in the **Processing Toolbox**. I had the same issue.